# Auto-setting fields, when creating a new task

Tags: jira

I'm working in a company where we (like a bunch of others) have made some chrome plated Jira-setup. In this setup, whenever we make a task, some of the fields 99% of the time should be the same (for me). Such as:

- Priority: Major
- Add to queue: Custom Created Que
- Sprint: Week 36 + 37

Can I somehow set that as the default values, when I create a task, so it's faster/better to create tasks?

The curve-ball is that I can't access the global administration. But due to the size of my company, small requests and modifications like this one, is extremely low on the priority-list. And I don't feel like playing golf with a manager, just to get this done.

---

### Solution attempt 1: Search the web

Here are a bunch of places, where the same thing has been attempted:

- [Setting default value for priority field](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Service-Management/Setting-default-value-for-priority-field/qaq-p/770467). I couldn't find any 'Priority Schemes' anywhere in my settings.
- [Change default priority for a project](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/Change-default-priority-for-a-project/qaq-p/1534341). Requires some admin Jira-permissions.
- [Jira documentation on Managing Priorities](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/defining-priority-field-values-938847101.html). Doesn't mention anything user-specific.

### Solution attempt 2: Dedicated "Create Task"-page + get parameters

I figured that if there was a dedicated "Create Task"-page, such as:

```
                                                                       |--- Create Issue
                                                                       v

https://mycompanyslug.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/MYPROJECT/create-issue
```

Because if so, then maybe something like this was made:

```
https://mycompanyslug.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/MYPROJECT/create-issue&priority=major
```

But I couldn't find that.

### Solution attempt 3: Set default values of those fields

Maybe it was possible to make those fields auto-fill, whenever I'm making a new task?
In a setting somewhere?

I couldn't find that.

Comment: The option 2 only works on Jira Server. Last time I checked Jira Cloud didn't accept more than a few key fields as parameters (such as project and type).

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 3 is actually the easiest to implement for a team managed project.

However, if you're project is Company Managed, you will need administrative permissions in the project. If this is the case, the easiest route would be to ask for Admin permissions over your project.

You are looking for the issue type permissions:

```
https://MYCOMPANY.atlassian.net/jira/software/projects/MYPROJECT/settings/issuetypes/
```

Here you can modify the request types so that they come with default values. Here I have pre-populated the default value for the Priority of the "Task" Issue type.

[image: a screenshot of the issue settings in jira software (cloud edition)]

### Use Jira Automation!

I'm a big fan of the automation so here's how you might achieve those same results with an automated task.

```
https://MYCOMPANY.atlassian.net/jira/software/projects/MYPROJECT/settings/automation#
```

You can create a new rule that runs on newly created issues!

[image: new issue starter rule in jira automation]

This task checks all new issues in your project and then you can run actions on it like updating fields that are important.

[image: a screenshot from jira software automation builder showing the options for editing a newly created field]

Automation rules will require less permissions, and are quite the rabbit hole. I recommend learning about [Jira smart values](https://support.atlassian.com/cloud-automation/docs/jira-smart-values-issues/) if you go this route.

Comment: Jira automation is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Although Alex answer pointing to **Jira automation is definitely the way to go here**, for completeness I believe worth raising how option 2 would work (and where it wouldn't).

**Caveat:** it is heavily restricted in *jira Cloud* (although the basic parameters such as project and issue type are still there).

**How to use:** you have to construct the link in the following format:
[Jira BASE URL]/secure/CreateIssueDetails!init.jspa?[ARGUMENTS]">[DESCRIPTION]

**Example:** I use this:
https://.atlassian.net/secure/CreateIssue.jspa?issuetype=10989&pid=11668&summary=Test

**Time saving trick:** Specially if you, like me, hate wasting time, you can save this link in your favourites (let's call it "new story"), so next time say you want to raise a new Story, you simply open a new chrome tab and type new story  and the link will open with prefilled fields.

I was used to use it in Jira Server and you can even fully customise (with a bit of effort) the whole description using tables and emojis. As the link grows bigger, it's suggested to use an URL shortener.

**Further reading:** Full explanation and more details can be found at [Atlassian site](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-create-issues-using-direct-html-links-in-jira-server-159474.html).